# How to install gcc on openwrt?

Tags: openwrt, opkg

I'm trying to install gcc on openwrt with the following command:

```
opkg install gcc
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
/bin/ash: gcc: not found
root@OpenWrt:/mp1# opkg install gcc
Unknown package 'gcc'.
Collected errors:
 * opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package gcc.
```

I tried updating opkg using `opkg update`, but I get the following:

```
Downloading http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05/x86/generic/packages
wget: bad address 'downloads.openwrt.org'
Downloading http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05/x86/generic/packages
wget: bad address 'downloads.openwrt.org'
Signature check failed.
Remove wrong Signature file.
Downloading http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05/x86/generic/packages
wget: bad address 'downloads.openwrt.org'
Downloading http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05/x86/generic/packages
wget: bad address 'downloads.openwrt.org'
Signature check failed.
Remove wrong Signature file.
Downloading http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05/x86/generic/packages
wget: bad address 'downloads.openwrt.org'
Downloading http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05/x86/generic/packages
wget: bad address 'downloads.openwrt.org'
Signature check failed.
Remove wrong Signature file.
Downloading http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05/x86/generic/packagez
wget: bad address 'downloads.openwrt.org'
Downloading http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05/x86/generic/packageo
wget: bad address 'downloads.openwrt.org'
Signature check failed.
Remove wrong Signature file.
Downloading http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05/x86/generic/packages
wget: bad address 'downloads.openwrt.org'
Downloading http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05/x86/generic/packaget
wget: bad address 'downloads.openwrt.org'
Signature check failed.
Remove wrong Signature file.
Downloading http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05/x86/generic/packages
wget: bad address 'downloads.openwrt.org'
Downloading http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05/x86/generic/packages
wget: bad address 'downloads.openwrt.org'
Signature check failed.
Remove wrong Signature file.
Collected errors:
 * opkg_download: Failed to download http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/b
 * opkg_download: Failed to download http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/1
 * opkg_download: Failed to download http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/1
 * opkg_download: Failed to download http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/0
 * opkg_download: Failed to download http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/ 
 * opkg_download: Failed to download http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/1
 * opkg_download: Failed to download http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/1
 * opkg_download: Failed to download http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/c
 * opkg_download: Failed to download http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/u
 * opkg_download: Failed to download http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/1
 * opkg_download: Failed to download http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/1
 * opkg_download: Failed to download http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/1
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly sure you do not have an internet connection or your DNS is somehow messed up and does not resolve 'downloads.openwrt.org' to an IP address.

You could try to `ping 8.8.8.8` and see whether you have a working internet connection. Then attempt to `ping google.com` (or `host downloads.openwrt.org`) to see whether your DNS is working properly.

Alternatively, I am fairly sure you can build an OpenWRT image with GCC yourself. Here's a good tutorial on how you can do it: https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-developer/quickstart-build-images